# Python module not showing up in sys.modules

Tags: python, installation, package, python-module

I have installed some packages by unpackaging the tar.gz and running setup.py.

I am checking by

```
>>> import sys
>>> '[packagename]' in sys.modules
```

but it keeps saying `False`, for all of them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sys.modules` only shows modules that have already been loaded into your environment.

> ## [sys.**modules**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)
>
> This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules
> which have already been loaded. This can be manipulated to force
> reloading of modules and other tricks. However, replacing the
> dictionary will not necessarily work as expected and deleting
> essential items from the dictionary may cause Python to fail.

To get the behaviour you want, you will need to import the module first:

```
import sys
import packagename
'packagename' in sys.modules #True
```

#### Console

If you are in the console, and want to check if you have a module available, just try to import it. If it doesn't exist, you will get an error:

```
>>> import packagename
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packagename'
```

#### Code

If you are writing code and want a clean way to check if the module exists before you use it, it is [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/3.12/glossary.html#term-EAFP).

```
try:
    import packagename
except ImportError:
    #handle the error
```

Answer (score 0):

I have executed `conda update --all` in my virtual environment and afterwards in the 'base' environment, and the error was gone. The error was still there after the update of my virtual environment. That is why I think that it is caused by two different versions (in my case numpy: `ImportError: parent 'numpy' not in sys.modules`) in the virtual env and the 'base' env.